# How to add a number to an integer like a string

Tags: c++, integer

In C++ I am trying to add two integers together. I don't want this:

5 + 5 = 10

I want it to be:

5 + 5 = 55

How can I add two integers together like strings. I know how to do this but it would be a lot of code and I'm just wondering if there's a short version under four lines.

Edit : Since Mingw doesn't properly support some C++11 features like to_string(), itoa() and that I'm looking for something that doesn't use a C++11 features.

Comment: `std::to_string(5) + std::to_string(5)` ?

Comment: Mingw does not support C++11 features such as to_string.

Comment: you should state that in your question. `to_string` can be implemented thanks to `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an `int` as result, multiply with the base:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
int c = 10 * a + b;  // 55
```

If you want the result to be a `std::string`, use `std::to_string` (since C++11):

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
std::string c = std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b);  // "55"
```

Before C++11, you can use a `std::stringstream`:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << a << b;
std::string c = ss.str();  // "55"
```

Comment: Is there any other easier way without using C++11 features since I'm using Mingw and it has bugs or rather it just doesn't support C++11 features yet so I can't use to_string.

Comment: @Hydra Before C++11, you would use a `std::stringstream`. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not adding that originally in my question. Your example works perfectly and I've implemented it and accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main(){

 int value1 = 5;
 int value2 = 4;

  string put_together = to_string(value1) + to_string(value2);

  return 0 ;
 }
```